# html/css: popup form centered horizontally and vertically and blur the whole background

Tags: css

Web newbie here. Trying out something at https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_popup_form.

below html/css is from the left frame of above URL.

how do I:

1. get the popup form to be aligned center horizontally/vertically
2. Blur the whole background when popup form is displayed

thank you.

```js
function openForm() {
  document.getElementById("myForm").style.display = "table-cell";
}

function closeForm() {
  document.getElementById("myForm").style.display = "none";
}
```

```css
body {font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;}
* {box-sizing: border-box;}

/* Button used to open the contact form - fixed at the bottom of the page */
.open-button {
  background-color: #555;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px 20px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 1.0;
  position: relative;
  /*
  bottom: 23px;
  right: 28px;
  */
  width: 280px;
}

/* The popup form - hidden by default */
.form-popup {
      height:80%;
      width:80%;
      margin:0 auto;
      
      position:fixed;
      top: 0;
      right: 10;
      

      z-index:10;
      display:none;
      /* background: url(login.png) no-repeat; */
      border:5px solid #cccccc;
      border-radius:10px;
         text-align: center;
   vertical-align: middle;
      
/*
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  top: 0;
  opacity: 1.0;
  border: 3px solid #f1f1f1;
  z-index: 9;
  */
}

/* Add styles to the form container */
.form-container {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
background-color: white;
  opacity: 1.0;
}

/* Full-width input fields */
.form-container input[type=text], .form-container input[type=password] {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 15px;
  margin: 5px 0 22px 0;
  border: none;
  background: #f1f1f1;
}

/* When the inputs get focus, do something */
.form-container input[type=text]:focus, .form-container input[type=password]:focus {
  background-color: #ddd;
  outline: none;
}

/* Set a style for the submit/login button */
.form-container .btn {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px 20px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom:10px;
  opacity: 0.8;
}

/* Add a red background color to the cancel button */
.form-container .cancel {
  background-color: red;
}

/* Add some hover effects to buttons */
.form-container .btn:hover, .open-button:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<h2>Popup Form</h2>
<p>Click on the button at the bottom of this page to open the login form.</p>
<p>Note that the button and the form is fixed - they will always be positioned to the bottom of the browser window.</p>

<button class="open-button" onclick="openForm()">Open Form</button>

<div class="form-popup" id="myForm">
  <form action="/action_page.php" class="form-container">
    <h1>Login</h1>

    <label for="email"><b>Email</b></label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Email" name="email" required>

    <label for="psw"><b>Password</b></label>
    <input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="psw" required>

    <button type="submit" class="btn">Login</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn cancel" onclick="closeForm()">Close</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

first add div with main id to html open after body tag and close before button.
You can add something like this in `openForm` function :

`document.getElemntById("main").style.opacity = "0.5";`

and reset it by add this to `closeForm` function :

`document.getElemntById("main").style.opacity = "1";`

Comment: <body>
<div id="main"></div>

Comment: I added div with id "main" as below to body.

<body>
<div id="main">
:
</div>
<button..
:
</body>

And added the lines you said to openForm and closeForm. when i open form i still see content of main page. Also how do i center the form?

Comment: sorry replace this with opacity style :

Comment: document.getElementById("main").styel.filter = "grayscale(1) blur (2px);

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of ways to go about centering something.

An easy way is to use fixed positioning like you have (relative to the browser window) and then set the top/left offsets to 50%; Now you need to use transforms to draw the object back half it's width and height so its centered.

There are also several ways to blur a background, but another easy way (not fully supported everywhere though) is to use the CSS `backdrop-filter`

```css
body {
 background: transparent url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1595226446403-63b64dfb067a?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=634&q=80) center center no-repeat;
 background-size: cover;
}

#popup {
 position: fixed;
 width: 80%;
 height: 50%;
 top: 50%;
 left: 50%;
 transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
 border: 2px solid white;
 border-radius: 10px;
 padding: 10px;
 
 /* you should use @supports for this to make sure it works in the viwers browser */
 -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(10px);
 backdrop-filter: blur(10px);
 background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25);
    
}
```

```html
<div id="popup">
  overlay
</div>
```

**Edit:** I just realized you asked how to blur the entire background... It's almost the same except you add a wrapper with the blur and position that relative to the window.

```css
body {
 background: transparent url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1595226446403-63b64dfb067a?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=634&q=80) center center no-repeat;
 background-size: cover;
}

#popupWrapper {
  position: fixed;
  top:0; right:0; bottom:0; left:0;
  /* this forces covering entire window */
  
  /* you should use @supports for this to make sure it works in the viwers browser */
 -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(10px);
 backdrop-filter: blur(10px);
 background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
}

#popup {
 position: absolute;
 width: 80%;
 height: 50%;
 top: 50%;
 left: 50%;
 transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
 border: 2px solid white;
 border-radius: 10px;
 padding: 10px;

 background-color: white;
 box-shadow: 4px 2px 15px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}
```

```html
<div id="popupWrapper">
  <div id="popup">Overlay</div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you. your solution worked for centering. i applied the css to to my class:

    .form-popup {

 position: fixed;
 width: 75%;
 height: auto;
 top: 50%;
 left: 50%;
 transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
 border: 2px solid white;
 border-radius: 10px;
 padding: 0px;
 
 
          z-index:10;
          display:none;
          /* background: url(login.png) no-repeat; */
          border:5px solid #cccccc;
          border-radius:10px;
             text-align: center;
       vertical-align: middle;
          
    }

Answer (score 0):

use this for blur part :

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <style>
    body {font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;}
    * {box-sizing: border-box;}

    /* Button used to open the contact form - fixed at the bottom of the page */
    .open-button {
      background-color: #555;
      color: white;
      padding: 16px 20px;
      border: none;
      cursor: pointer;
      opacity: 1.0;
      position: relative;
      /*
      bottom: 23px;
      right: 28px;
      */
      width: 280px;
    }

    /* The popup form - hidden by default */
    .form-popup {
          height:80%;
          width:80%;
          margin:0 auto;
          
          position:fixed;
          top: 0;
          right: 10;
          

          z-index:10;
          display:none;
          /* background: url(login.png) no-repeat; */
          border:5px solid #cccccc;
          border-radius:10px;
             text-align: center;
       vertical-align: middle;
          
    /*
      display: none;
      position: fixed;
      bottom: 0;
      top: 0;
      opacity: 1.0;
      border: 3px solid #f1f1f1;
      z-index: 9;
      */
    }

    /* Add styles to the form container */
    .form-container {
      max-width: 100%;
      max-height: 100%;
      padding: 10px;
    background-color: white;
      opacity: 1.0;
    }

    /* Full-width input fields */
    .form-container input[type=text], .form-container input[type=password] {
      width: 100%;
      padding: 15px;
      margin: 5px 0 22px 0;
      border: none;
      background: #f1f1f1;
    }

    /* When the inputs get focus, do something */
    .form-container input[type=text]:focus, .form-container input[type=password]:focus {
      background-color: #ddd;
      outline: none;
    }

    /* Set a style for the submit/login button */
    .form-container .btn {
      background-color: #4CAF50;
      color: white;
      padding: 16px 20px;
      border: none;
      cursor: pointer;
      width: 100%;
      margin-bottom:10px;
      opacity: 0.8;
    }

    /* Add a red background color to the cancel button */
    .form-container .cancel {
      background-color: red;
    }

    /* Add some hover effects to buttons */
    .form-container .btn:hover, .open-button:hover {
      opacity: 1;
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
<div id="main">
    <h2>Popup Form</h2>
    <p>Click on the button at the bottom of this page to open the login form.</p>
    <p>Note that the button and the form is fixed - they will always be positioned to the bottom of the browser window.</p>
</div>
    <button class="open-button" onclick="openForm()">Open Form</button>

    <div class="form-popup" id="myForm">
      <form action="/action_page.php" class="form-container">
        <h1>Login</h1>

        <label for="email"><b>Email</b></label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Email" name="email" required>

        <label for="psw"><b>Password</b></label>
        <input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="psw" required>

        <button type="submit" class="btn">Login</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn cancel" onclick="closeForm()">Close</button>
      </form>
    </div>

    <script>
    function openForm() {
      document.getElementById("myForm").style.display = "table-cell";
  document.getElementById("main").style.filter = "grayscale(1) blur(2px)" ;
    }

    function closeForm() {
      document.getElementById("myForm").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("main").style.filter = "grayscale(0) blur(0)" ;
    }
    </script>

    </body>
    </html>
```